# Handling data references/pointers in a file?

Tags: c#, c++, file

I'm working with a binary file format. I'll try to make this as simple as possible because it's quite hard to explain.

The data structures that get written to the file may contain 'pointers' (ie. a pointer to a string that is in another location in  the file, or a pointer to another structure within the file. A better word for 'pointer' would be 'offset', ie. a structure contains the OFFSET of the string within the file).

A quick example:

```
struct ExampleStruct {
    public string Text;
    public int Number;
};
```

The 'Text' string member will be written at the beginning of the file, and NOT be included in the serialized struct.

So, essentially, the struct will look like this in the file:

```
struct ExampleStruct {
    public uint TextLocationOffset;
    public int Number;
};
```

...'TextLocationOffset' is an offset to where the string 'Text' is located within the file.

So, after I have that, I then need a "relocation table" - essentially a list of double pointers that point to data pointers within the file. (does that make sense?)

So, since I wrote that ExampleStruct to my file, and it contains a 'pointer' (TextLocationOffset), my "relocation table" would consist of:

```
public uint TextLocationOffset_LocationOffset;
```

...'TextLocationOffset_LocationOffset' contains the OFFSET of 'TextLocationOffset' within the file.

Does that all make sense? I tried to simplify it as much as possible.

My problem is, how would I keep track of all the pointers/double pointers/relocations in C#? Data is constantly being added to the byte[] array that I have, so offsets will be changing constantly.

This is easy in C++, because I can get a double pointer of whatever is being 'relocated', and then I can change the original 'pointer' (in my example, 'TextLocationOffset') to the correct offset, and I can then find the location of the 'TextLocationOffset' value and add that to my relocation table.

Sorry if that makes no sense. I tried asking this a few weeks ago but got no replies, I might be making it sound confusing.

I just need a way to keep track of all of these in my code... Any tips?

P.S. If you need more thorough examples I'll be happy to provide. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binary file format - data 'relocations'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183384/binary-file-format-data-relocations)

Answer (score 0):

Use a database table - all this work has been done.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at other ways to serialize and deserialize your data. Keeping track of relocations and offsets in a managed application is doing the unnecessary unless you have extremely exceptional scenarios. SO users could better guide you if you let us know more about what you are trying to achieve in terms of functionality.

Comment: It is actually a binary file format for a 3D game. The files contain "structures" - like textures, icons, textstrings, etc. At the beginning of the file there are data 'identifiers' that contain an offset to the entry point of the structure data. I have come up with a solution of having a "Location" struct that contains the file offset for each structure, which seems to work fine. I was just wondering if there was a simpler way to do this. :)